# Unable to receive data from ROS Master using Matlab

Tags: ros, matlab, rosmaster, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to connect to ROS network using Matlab and plot the laser scanner data

- The ROS framework runs on a rover with IP address: `160.80.97.150.`
  The rover is publishing laserscanner data on the **/scan** topic
- Matlab runs on another computer with IP: `160.80.97.241`

The port 11311 on the rover is opened:

```
heavylab@HeavyLab:~$ nmap 160.80.97.150 -p 11311

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-01 14:30 CEST
Nmap scan report for 160.80.97.150
Host is up (0.000030s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE
11311/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

**The Problem**

I am able to see the published topics from matlab but they seems empty. The receive command returns an error.

```
    % Connect to a remote ROS instance on port 11311
    rosinit('http://160.80.97.150:11311', 'NodeHost', '160.80.97.241')
    
    % Check for topics
    rostopic list
                                                                       
/scan            
    
    % Echo for /scan topic
    laser = rossubscriber('/scan')


laser = 

  Subscriber with properties:

        TopicName: '/scan'
      MessageType: 'sensor_msgs/LaserScan'
    LatestMessage: [0x1 LaserScan]
       BufferSize: 1
    NewMessageFcn: []
    
    % Receive Scan data
    scandata = receive(laser,10)
    
     Error using robotics.ros.Subscriber/receive
     (line 291)
     The function did not receive any data and timed
     out.
```

Do have any advice?

**EDIT**

Here is the output of the rosnode ping from Matlab:

```
 rosnode ping /rosout
    Pinging the /rosout node with a timeout of 3 seconds.
    Received no ping response.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230737/unable-to-receive-data-from-ros-master-using-matlab/) by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2016-04-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-01**:
Are these both Linux machines? Do you have a working DNS server that can resolve both hostnames to their IPs? What is the output of `rosnode ping <nodename>`?

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-04-01**:
Yes, they are both linux machines. No I don't have any DNS. I added the output of the command in the question

**Comment by [runbren](https://answers.ros.org/users/27668/runbren/) on 2016-08-02**:
I'm getting the exact same issue. Any progress on an answer?

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-08-03**:
No Nothing

**Comment by [wangxvx](https://answers.ros.org/users/22453/wangxvx/) on 2016-11-14**:
I meet the same problem too. And there is no answer to the issue on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem following an answer below:
http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119559-why-is-the-ros-subscriber-callback-in-matlab-not-triggered-when-messages-are-published-from-an-exter

---

Originally posted by [wangxvx](https://answers.ros.org/users/22453/wangxvx/) with karma: 36 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-15**:
That is exactly what I wrote above in my answer: *always* make sure you either have a working DNS setup for all computers in your network, or use `ROS_IP` *or* `ROS_HOSTNAME` together with a proper value for `ROS_MASTER_URI`. But thanks for posting the URL @wangxvx.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-15**:
Note that the suggested 'fix' on the mathworks support page (setting `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` to hard-coded values) will only work if you're not on a network with DHCP that (frequently) changes your computer's IP address. If you are, you'll run into even more problems.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure what Mathworks recommends in their documentation, but be sure to set correct values for the `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` environment variables on all involved hosts. `ROS_IP` should equal the IP address of the host, `ROS_MASTER_URI` should point to the rover's IP.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1